# Expand an Array

Tags: code-golf, array, matrix

**Expand an array to all directions by duplicating the outer elements**

You will be given two inputs: an array and the expansion degree
For example if I give you `[[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]]` and `3`,
you must output:

```
1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 5 6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7 8 9 9 9 9
7 7 7 7 8 9 9 9 9
7 7 7 7 8 9 9 9 9
7 7 7 7 8 9 9 9 9
```

As you can see the given array is in the center and all the outer elements have expanded:
`1` -> 3 times up, 3 times left and also to every position of the upper left corner
`2`->  3 times up
`5`->  is not an outer element
etc

here are some more test cases to make things clearer

```
Input   [[4,5,6]],0   

Output   
4 5 6


Input  [[1]],2   

Output   

1 1 1 1 1  
1 1 1 1 1   
1 1 1 1 1  
1 1 1 1 1   
1 1 1 1 1   

Input  [[1,2,3]],2  

Output  
1 1 1 2 3 3 3   
1 1 1 2 3 3 3  
1 1 1 2 3 3 3
1 1 1 2 3 3 3
1 1 1 2 3 3 3    

Input  [[1,2,3][11,22,33][111,222,333][1111,2222,3333]],1   

Output  
   1       1       2       3       3
   1       1       2       3       3
  11      11      22      33      33
 111     111     222     333     333
1111    1111    2222    3333    3333
1111    1111    2222    3333    3333
```

You can use as many whitespaces as you like.
But the output has to be a `mXn` array just like it is shown here.
You cannot output a list of lists.

This is [codegolf](/questions/tagged/codegolf)
Shortest answer on bytes wins

Comment: Is output formatted like [this](https://tio.run/##S87PzU0sSfz/31DBSMGYyxBIAWkQA8QCMcFsMAfMM1YwAYL//wE) valid? (output is in input)

Comment: @H.PWiz Yes,it is.

Comment: "You cannot output a list of lists." seems like an unnecessary output restriction to me.

Comment: Probably so, because the stringize part of my answer takes 41 chars, while the "actual" part only takes 19 chars.

Comment: Test cases are not an acceptable alternative to a clear specification.

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, 35 bytes

```matlab
@(a,x)padarray(a,[x x],'replicate')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNRp0KzIDElsagosRLIia5QqIjVUS9KLcjJTE4sSVXX/J9mq5CYV2zNlahgqxDNZahgpGDMZaJgqmDGZa5goWAZa81VAZQxtuZKAxv2HwA)

Comment: Is this a builtin in Octave?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It belongs to the image processing package.

Answer (score 4):

## [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html), 27 bytes

```matlab
@(a,n)padarray(a,[n,n],'r')
```

The key over the Octave solution is that Matlab accepts partial option strings when they are unambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
th2Y5I4$Ya
```

Port of [@rahnema1's Octave answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145923/36398).

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyTDKNLU00QlMvH/f2OuaEMFIwVjawUTBVMFM2sFcwULBctYAA)

#### Explanation

```
t      % Implicit input: number, n. Duplicate
h      % Concatenate. Gives an array [n,n]
2Y5    % Push 'replicate' (predefined literal). Will be used as an input flag
I      % Push 3. Will be used as equivalent to an input flag
4$     % Specify that the next function will use 4 inputs
Ya     % Call 'padarray' with 4 inputs. This takes the array as implicit
       % input. Number 3 as third input is interpreted as the input flag 
       % 'both'. So the function pads the array (first input) by n in each
       % dimension (second input) by replicating the border (third input) in 
       % both directions (fourth input). Implicit display
```

Comment: Explanation please?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Added

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
;ṫ¥0$¡Ṛ$⁺Zµ⁺G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/64c7Vh5YaqBxa@HDnLJVHjbuiDm0Fku7///@PjjbUUTDSUTCO1VGINgSxQRwoD8wF82ECEBGIkHFs7H9DAA)

Comment: I will NEVER learn how to use Jelly...

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>33</s> <s>28</s> 23 bytes

```
F2Fø2FR¤¸«]øεD€gZs-ú}ø»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fzcjt8A4jt6BDSw7tOLQ69vCOc1tdHjWtSY8q1j28q/bwjkO7//835oqONtQx0jGO1Yk2MdExNdUxMwMyzc3NdSwsLHQsLS1jYwE) <s>15</s> 10 bytes of actual code, the rest is formatting the output. Explanation:

```
       ¤                Copy last element
        ¸               Turn it into a list
         «              Concatenate
    2F                  Repeat twice
      R                 Reverse list each time
 2F                     Repeat twice
   ø                    Transpose list each time
F                       Repeat the given number of times
          ]             Close all the loops
           ø            Transpose the array
             D          Duplicate
              €g        Take length of each number
                Z       Get the maximum
                 s-     Subtract each length from the maximum
                   ú    Pad with that number of spaces
            ε       }   For each row (column originally)
                     ø  Transpose back
                      » Join with spaces and newlines
```

Formatting costs 2 bytes if I copy @ErikTheOutgolfer's output format for 12 bytes:

```
F2Fø2FR¤¸«]»
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>138</s> 113 bytes

*-9 bytes thanks to @JonathanFrech*
*-16 bytes thanks to @Lynn*

```python
a,n=input()
for e in a[:1]*n+a+n*a[-1:]:print' '.join('%*s'%(len(`max(sum(a,[]))`),n)for n in e[:1]*n+e+n*e[-1:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5LDoIwEED3nKIhIbRlNBbRBQknaZrQ6BgxMiV8Ejw9tpWNq3lvMW9m@MxPR@V2c3ds0jTdLFDT0bDMXCQPNzJkHTGra2UkFbYgafVB1aYexo7mnOXHl@uI55mc8oy/kXjb25VPS88taCNEK4BECFEI4R5CH8IYElssJf52giveWPhEVpvWFVzgagycEq2Vn2WYUML5j0ErD55@GDjIblGjhy31BQ)

Comment: [129 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY5BCsIwFET3OUUIiEn7FVOri0JP8gmYaMSI/pZaQU8fk@jG1byBmWHG93wZqInH4eR7IUS0QH2g8TlLxWyPDjttKqpdTZXDle7MeZi444G4NSyzL/yL2RSzJdaNU6B5yZfr6xBIikX1EAt58yQPd/uSj@ddWkCj1EEBqTxEecirWIosfWH@5Y88P6vaiNjCDvbGwIYh6qRNVmhg@8eAOkGiL2bO5ueKLT639Ac); using string formatting to pad the output.

Comment: [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY5LDoIwEED3nKIhIbRlNBbRBQknaZrQ6BgxMiV8Ejw9tpWNq3lvMW9m@MxPR@V2c3ds0jTdLFDT0bDMXCQPNzJkHTGra2UkFbYgafVB1aYexo7mnOXHl@uI55mc8oy/kXjb25VPS88taCNEK4BECFEI4R5CH8IYElssJf52giveWPhEVpvWFVzgagycEq2Vn2WYUML5j0ErD55@GDjIblGjhy31BQ).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
2F2F¤¸².×«R}ø}»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fyM3I7dCSQzsObdI7PP3Q6qDawztqD@3@/z862lBHwUhHwThWRyHaREfBVEfBDMQ011Gw0FGwjI3lMgEA)

Yes, this [output format](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/145921/expand-an-array/145925#comment357035_145921) is [valid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/145921/expand-an-array/145925#comment357036_145921).

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7, 74 characters

Pretty straightforward: uses numpy padding and regex to force a return string without brackets. This code returns an anonymous lambda.

```
import numpy,re;lambda a,n:re.sub('[\[\]]', '',str(numpy.pad(a,n,'edge')))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>94</s> <s>89</s> <s>86</s> 82 bytes

```python
a,n=input()
for l in a[:1]*n+a+n*a[-1:]:print' '.join(map(str,l[:1]*n+l+n*l[-1:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1LDsIgEED3nIJ0099opFYXTXqSCQtSa8TgQBATPT0CduNq3kvezLhPuFka4mIv61xVVVRAsyb3Ck3LrtZzwzVxhZOQHfWqp07hTkxycl5TqHm9v1tNzUO55hk8mC00KTQlbNtYUpaOM7a@14XnX90YEUc4wVlKODBEkeaQJwxw/GNAkSDRDzNn2axo8bwlvg)